# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'product' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic3

Im trying to print my information that i sent in my frontend but im getting this error , i do not know whats going on,my query is fine because when i print in console its works fine

**ERROR:** https://snag.gy/dAFq4k.jpg

**HOME.TS**

```
export class HomePage {
  options:BarcodeScannerOptions;
  encodText:string='';
  resul:string;
  encodedData:any={};
  scannedData:any={};
  public resultado: string;

  public product= [];
  // public product= {};


public resultadoref: firebase.database.Reference = firebase.database().ref('/productos');

  constructor(public fdb: AngularFireDatabase,public navCtrl: NavController,
  public scanner:BarcodeScanner,private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

  }

  public cargarvalor(){
    var referenceresultado= this.resultadoref.orderByChild('Producto').equalTo(this.resultado);
    referenceresultado.on('value', function(snapshot){
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
    // this.product=snapshot.val();
    this.product= snapshot.val();
    });
  }
}
```

**HOME.HTML**

```
<div>

        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="resultado"></ion-input>
        <button ion-button (click)="cargarvalor()">Buscar</button>


    </div>

        <div class="row header">
          <div class="col">Producto</div>
          <div class="col">Descripcion</div>
          <div class="col">Precio</div>
        </div>

       <div class="row">

        {{ product.Producto }}
        {{ product.Valor }}
        {{ product.Descripcion }}


       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` changes reference in the callback. Therefore `this.product` doesn't refer to your array. `this` is actually null because of how the callback is called.

Please try this modification:

```
public cargarvalor(){
   var self = this;
   var referenceresultado = this.resultadoref.orderByChild('Producto').equalTo(this.resultado);
   referenceresultado.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      self.product= snapshot.val();
   });
}
```

Comment: I understand your point , currently do not show me any error, but i can not see the retrieve information its just appeared in my console